# Scraping through the h4 tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

How would I get both the link and the text from the H4 tag in python?

h4 tag image

[image]

I have the following script which runs through different pages and downloads the 'class' data:

```py
pages = np.arange(1, 2, 1)
data=[]

for page in pages:
    
    page="https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/tag/Infographics/p" + str(page) 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\ssakorkar\Desktop\chromedriver")
    driver.get(page)  
    sleep(randint(2,10))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    my_table = soup.find_all(class_=['author'])

    for tag in my_table:
        data.append(tag.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get text + link from `<h4>` tags you can use next example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


for page in range(1, 2):
    page = "https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/tag/Infographics/p" + str(
        page
    )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(page).content, "html.parser")
    for h4 in soup.select("h4"):
        print(h4.a["href"])
        print(h4.get_text(strip=True))
        print()
```

Prints:

```
https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/updated-can-an-np-do-that-infographic
Updated: Can an NP Do That? [INFOGRAPHIC]

https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/locum-tenens-for-dentists-infographic
Locum Tenens for Dentists [INFOGRAPHIC]

https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/can-a-crna-do-that-infographic
Can a CRNA Do That? [INFOGRAPHIC]

https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/surviving-the-physician-shortage-infographic
Surviving the Physician Shortage [INFOGRAPHIC]

https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/get-the-facts-busting-locum-tenens-myths-infographic
Get the Facts: Busting Locum Tenens Myths [INFOGRAPHIC]

https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/the-truth-about-medical-billing-infographic
The Truth About Medical Billing [INFOGRAPHIC]
```

---

EDIT: To add titles/links to a list, you can use:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = []
for page in range(1, 2):
    page = "https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/tag/Infographics/p" + str(
        page
    )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(page).content, "html.parser")
    for h4 in soup.select("h4"):
        data.append((h4.get_text(strip=True), h4.a["href"]))


print(data)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    (
        "Updated: Can an NP Do That? [INFOGRAPHIC]",
        "https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/updated-can-an-np-do-that-infographic",
    ),
    (
        "Locum Tenens for Dentists [INFOGRAPHIC]",
        "https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/locum-tenens-for-dentists-infographic",
    ),
    (
        "Can a CRNA Do That? [INFOGRAPHIC]",
        "https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/can-a-crna-do-that-infographic",
    ),
    (
        "Surviving the Physician Shortage [INFOGRAPHIC]",
        "https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/surviving-the-physician-shortage-infographic",
    ),
    (
        "Get the Facts: Busting Locum Tenens Myths [INFOGRAPHIC]",
        "https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/get-the-facts-busting-locum-tenens-myths-infographic",
    ),
    (
        "The Truth About Medical Billing [INFOGRAPHIC]",
        "https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/the-truth-about-medical-billing-infographic",
    ),
]
```

---

Or create DataFrame from `data`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["title", "link"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                     title                                                                                        link
0                Updated: Can an NP Do That? [INFOGRAPHIC]                 https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/updated-can-an-np-do-that-infographic
1                  Locum Tenens for Dentists [INFOGRAPHIC]                 https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/locum-tenens-for-dentists-infographic
2                        Can a CRNA Do That? [INFOGRAPHIC]                        https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/can-a-crna-do-that-infographic
3           Surviving the Physician Shortage [INFOGRAPHIC]          https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/surviving-the-physician-shortage-infographic
4  Get the Facts: Busting Locum Tenens Myths [INFOGRAPHIC]  https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/get-the-facts-busting-locum-tenens-myths-infographic
5            The Truth About Medical Billing [INFOGRAPHIC]           https://www.bartonassociates.com/blog/the-truth-about-medical-billing-infographic
```

Comment: Apologies, I dint mention it before. I want this added to a blank list. like I am doing with the 'data' list.

Its basically a dataframe of authors, links, blog name that I am trying to create